# Is there possible to determine parameter is one of the given collection types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Imagine I have a `Select` component like this [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/h7snq). For simplicity, we ignore other props.

Now we `Select` component just receive two props:

- **set** a set of string , `Select` component will render this set into a bunch of `Option` component.
- **defaultValue** is initial selected option, it is one of **set** props's value.

I assume two case. The case one should work well without warning

```
<Select set={["peter", "tom", "jos"]} defaultValue={"tom"} />
```

Case two should be warning in editor, because 'ben' is not in set.

```
<Select set={["peter", "tom", "jos"]}  defaultValue={'ben'} />
```

Can we do static check in case two instead of runtime check ?

Comment: Assuming you can change the definitions of `Select` or that you defined `Select` yourself ?

Comment: Yes I can change the definitions or write a new `Select` to do that. I wonder if I can do it check without these two methods ？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a type for such a component. It must be a generic component, that will infer the types of the string literals passed in as the `set` property:

```
function Select<T extends V[], V extends string>(p: { set: T, defaultValue: T[number] }) {
    return <div></div>
}
let s = () => <Select set={["peter", "tom", "jos"]} defaultValue="tom" />


let s2 = () => <Select set={["peter", "tom", "jos"]}  defaultValue="ben" /> // err
```

Without changing the definition of the original `Select` your only option would be to use a helper function to do the checking:

```
function Select(p: { set: string[], defaultValue: string }) {
    return <div></div>
}
function SelectData<T extends V[], V extends string>(p: { set: T, defaultValue: T[number] }) : { set: string[], defaultValue: string } {
    return p
}
let s = () => <Select {... SelectData({ set: ["peter", "tom", "jos"], defaultValue:"tom" })} />


let s2 = () => <Select {... SelectData({ set: ["peter", "tom", "jos"], defaultValue:"ben" })} /> // err
```

Comment: Thank you !! This is the answer I want !!